# FocusIn/FocusOut not generated

Tags: x11

Can someone please clarify the default focus handling of the X11 server? My understanding is that the focus 'follows the mouse' and sure enough if I move the mouse between separate terminals I can see the cursor changing as each window aquires/loses the focus.

But when I run two xev windows and move the pointer between them, I see plenty of MotionNotify/EnterNotify/LeaveNotify as the pointer moves from one window to another - but FocusIn and FocusOut are nowhere to be seen. Is this an oddity in xev? Is there some special mask or property which needs to be applied in order for these events to be generated?

Many thanks, R.

While I do not fully understand the answer(s), I am grateful to parkydr, minitech and any others who may have stopped by.

Thanks again, R.

Comment: This is dependent on the client, not the server, isn’t it? Which client are you using?

Comment: The client(s) in this case would be the two xev windows.

Comment: Er, sorry, your window manager. twm?

Comment: I am trying to understand the default behaviour of the X11 server and (as you correctly point out) a window manager might interfere with focus, so for this test I am running with no window manager: just X11 server, two urxvt windows each of which is running xev. 

Sorry if that was not clear before.

Comment: Huh. I don’t know a lot about that — how do you do it? (And have you tried with a window manager? I can get the FocusIn and FocusOut events when running one :D)

Comment: The principle is simple enough. My .xinitrc/.xsession simply spawns two rxvts.

It is no surprise that the events occur when you have a window manager - since it may be interfering and using SetInputFocus - that is precisely why I am trying without the window manager. It is almost as if the X11 server is changing the focus but not notifying clients.

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t understand what that looks like. What do you have in your .xinitrc/.xsession?

Comment: I don't have that machine in front of me at the moment - but pretty close to this:

`urxvt &
urxvt -g -0-0`

Comment: Oh. I can’t reproduce your focus-follows-mouse behaviour — the cursor stays the same — but I never thought there *was* any focus when you did that…

Comment: From [this](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/input-focus/), I’d guess that there is indeed no focus and the mouse pointer just determines where the events go.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway. I'll keep investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having focus refers to the window which receives keyboard input when you press a key.

The focus handling depends on your window manager. The most common mode is click to focus, which your window manager is set to, where you only get focus when you click on the window.  An alternative is that the keyboard focus follows the mouse, which is what you are expecting.

There should be a setting to change this in your window manager settings.

The cursor changing does not indicate focus, just that the terminal has defined a different cursor.

To demonstrate, open a terminal and an xev window.

- Click on the xev window and press a key, you will see key events.
- Move the mouse to the terminal window, you'll see the motion and leave events
- Press a key and you'll still see key events from xev
- Click on the terminal window, xev will give a focus out event
- Press a key, the characters will be displayed in the terminal window
- Move the mouse over the xev window and press a key, the character will still come out in the terminal window

Comment: Forgive me if this was not clear from my earlier text and comments. I am already well aware of all the points that you have made regarding window managers and focus. I am trying to understand the default operation of the **X11 server**. Since the window manager will interfere with focus I am therefore deliberately running this test with **no window manager**. Does that clarify things?

Comment: Just so that I understand the situation; 1) the X server is not reporting the focus change - even though it is clearly changing the focus and 2) the answer to the question was nowhere to be found in the main X11 protocol specification - but is instead in the 'ICCCM' documentation - which if I understand correctly is an extension to the main protocol.

Have I got that right?

Comment: Yes. (Re 2) The ICCCM is mentioned in the Xlib Programming Manual).

Comment: Re. 1) There's a difference between being given the input and taking the focus.