# SDL2 input focus

Tags: x11, sdl-2

I'm currently trying to build and run an UnrealEngine4 demo app, which uses SDL2, on a Linux armv7 embedded system with X server running but no window manager.

What I'm seeing is that the app is not responsive to keyboard events, although mouse works fine.

Digging further it turns out the problem is that UE4 ignores the keyboard event if the SDL_Event.key.windowID does not match the ID of the app's SDL_Window. I verified this by calling SDL_GetKeyboardFocus() and it turns out the window ID for the keyboard focus is 0 whereas the app's window's ID is 5.

Digging a bit further inside SDL2 it looks like the keyboard focus is set to a particular SDL window after a focusIn event is received from the X server. (see X11_DispatchEvent() in SDL_x11events.c).

It looks like if you're running X11 without a window manager however this focusIn event is never generated by the X-server as already answered here:

[FocusIn/FocusOut not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234136/focusin-focusout-not-generated)

After hacking X11_RaiseWindow() in SDL_x11windows.c by adding:

X11_XSetInputFocus(display, data->xwindow, RevertToParent, CurrentTime);
SDL_SetKeyboardFocus(data->window);

was able to finally get the keyboard events processed.

Does the above assessment sound correct ? If so is there a clean solution to this ? I'm still digging around but any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I've hit the same issue. It seems to me this should be the actual behavior in SDL, so you should file a bug report with them.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in SDL, which we just pushed a fix for:

https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/aa4e4768c6c1

This fix will be in SDL 2.0.4, and should bubble over to Unreal shortly thereafter.